# php shell_exec, in windows with Ñ letter ( latin)

Tags: php, windows, shell, latin

Im tryng to parse latin caracter, the path of a folder to ork arround it, creating files, deleting folders...
the path is:
c:\user\CAÑIZO
and when try to get it from shwll_Exec

```
$path = shell_exec("pwd");
    echo $path;
```

this is my output:
c:/user/CA├æIZO
so when i try to use opendir method, it give me an error that didn't find the path...
I`ve tried anythig, using icon, utf8-decode, utf8-encode.
And windows tell me that my encoding is utf8 , but....
And at last i cant rename my user of windows...

I tried to write directly the folder path:

```
if(opendir('c:\user\CAÑIZO')) echo "great"; 
    else echo "bad";
```

And the same didt find..

Any help is apreciated.

thanks

Comment: hi, i modified my post to put what i think you're saying

Comment: using chcp, no change for example echo of 'página' is 'pßgina'

Comment: none of the encodig give the correct result   
 $text = "A strange string to pass, maybe with some ø, æ, å characters."; 

foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){ 
        echo mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."\n";    
}